Psychonauts was unable to create the Direct3D device
Whenever I try to launch Psychonauts on Steam, then I get an error message popup saying:

Psychonauts Startup Problem


The game was unable to create the Direct3D device.


Please check to ensure your video drivers are installed properly

I'm not sure what to do. I'm running a laptop with Windows 11 and a Snapdragon X Elite X1E-78-100 CPU.
How can I get the game running?

Your laptop is using an ARM64 CPU, specifically the Qualcomm Snapdragon X Elite. This is different from the other CPUs that usually run Windows like x86 and x64/AMD64.
Windows on ARM uses an Emulator/Translation Layer called Prism, which allows x86 and x64/AMD64 programs to run on ARM64. Prism, like other Emulators and Translation Layers like WINE have limitations where not all of the programs will start and run properly (LTT tested a bunch of games, and a lot of them failed).
Sadly, this appears one of the cases where the game will not launch at all, and there is nothing that can be done without a developer debugging the problem. The only thing you can do for now is wait until a Windows update is released and fixes this issue.
